# Ruby on Rails newsletter verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I'm about to create a newsletter. But I don't want anybody to trash in custom emails.
What would be the best in my opinion is:
- send an email verification and only activate the email in the app when it's clicked on.

What would be the way to generate an activate link, is there a gem for this?

Comment: Devise does this out of the box.

Comment: See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise, and watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-devise-revised

Comment: ok so, figured  out, I create a new class in devise, where only the email needs to be set, yay, was that easy :) thx

Comment: If you found a solution to your own question, you should post an answer (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).  That way this question is helpful to others who are trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Devise** comes with email verification support.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 0):

https://rubygems.org/gems/devise

Confirmable: sends emails with confirmation instructions and verifies whether an account is already confirmed during sign in.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a DIY solution rather than the [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb) gem, you will need to: -

1. have a controller action accepting the subscribe form
2. create a db record (model) with `email`, `token`, `expire_at`
3. send a verification email with a confirmation url (e.g: `app.com/newsletters/confirm?email=aaa@gmail.com&token=abc123` )
4. have a controller action (e.g: `newsletters#confirm`) accepting the confirmation url
5. check `email` and `token` are match
6. check `token` has not been expired
7. mark `email` as *activated*

Basically, this is how devise handle it.

However, for most of the case, using devise is better than do it your own.